Как настроить DataGrip, чтобы IDE предлагала сменить истекший пароль?
Пользователь имеет доступ к БД (интересует в 1 очередь ORACLE), пароль имеет ограниченный срок жизни, после чего пользователь должен его сменить.
Если использовать Dbeaver - тот своевременно информирует об истекшем пароле и предлагает его сменить, отображая модальное окно.
DataGrip это не делает.
Есть ли возможность включить эту настройку, если она есть в принципе?

Пока никак: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-14118/Password-expiration-reminder
Но на Test Connection должен предложить
